# Execute line of code after returning value

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I'm trying to execute code after yield return. I have WebMethod that call's another method and I want to do some staff after returning value to WebMethod (execute method setNextCampaign())
Here is my code:

```
[WebMethod]
public long NextCall(long UserID)
{
    CampaignManagerExtended cacheCampaignManager = fillCampaignManager(false);

    return cacheCampaignManager.NextCall(UserID).First();
}



public IEnumerable<long> NextCall(long UserID)
        {
            UserExtended ue = null;
            try
            {
                if (!CacheUsers.ContainsKey(UserID))
                    AddUser(UserID);

                ue = CacheUsers.First(p => p.Key == UserID).Value;
                if (ue.NextCampaign != null)
                {
                    QueueItemPersonal qp = ue.NextFromPersonalQueue();
                    if (qp != null)
                    {

                        yield return qp.CampaignPersonID;
                    }
                    else 
                    { 
                        QueueItemScheduled qs = ue.NextCampaign.NextFromScheduleQueue();
                        if (qs != null)
                        {

                            yield return qs.CampaignPersonID;
                        }
                        else 
                        { 
                            QueueItemGeneral qg = ue.NextCampaign.NextFromGeneralQueue();
                            if (qg != null)
                            {

                                yield return qg.CampaignPersonID;
                            }                  
                            else
                                 yield return 0;
                        }
                    }
                    ue.NextCampaign.fillGeneralQueue();
                    ue.setNextCampaign();
                }
                else
                    yield return 0;

            }
            //catch
            //{
            //    yield return 0;
            //}
            finally
            {

            }
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: ue.NextCampaign.fillGeneralQueue();
ue.setNextCampaign(); this lines of code does not execute

Comment: Are you sure ue.NextCampaign isn't null? Maybe there's an exception thrown earlier? For some reason your code doesn't reach those methods, and I'd say it's either because you are going to the else block or you are kicked out of the try block.

Comment: I have brake points so I see what executes ue.NextCampaign is not null

Answer (score 5):

Instead of this

```
<some stuff>;
yield return <something>;
<some epilog stuff that should be executed after yield>
```

do this:

```
try
{
  <some stuff>;
  yield return <something>;
}
finally
{
  <some epilog stuff that should be executed after yield>
}
```

Comment: I tryed that but finally executes before  return cacheCampaignManager.NextCall(UserID).First();. I want to return that ID to client and after that execute ue.setNextCampaign();

Comment: Problem is you call `First()`, so after yield returns one item it's done with yielding. If you would call `Take(2).First()` then the code after first yield would also execute.

Comment: @Dialecticus +1 Good point, how about explaining it in your answer, instead of posting some garbage.

Comment: Not working return cacheCampaignManager.NextCall(UserID).Take(2).First();

Comment: @mcorluka you are still not enumerating the second item. Try this `return cacheCampaignManager.NextCall(UserID).Take(2).ToList().First();`

Comment: @I4V, now OP is using a bit of information intended for him to understand what's going on to "fix" the code in the wrong way. I feel that `Take(2).ToList().First()` should not be part of the answer.

Comment: @Dialecticus Of course, but it shows what is wrong in his code.

Comment: Is there a better way to do what I want to do(not with yield, something else maybe event)

Comment: @mcorluka it is difficult to say because it's unclear what you really want to achieve. What is it that you really want? Why do you want to "execute line of code after returning value"?

Answer (score 2):

Just save the yeild until you are ready to return it:

```
[WebMethod]
public long NextCall(long UserID)
{
    CampaignManagerExtended cacheCampaignManager = fillCampaignManager(false);

    return cacheCampaignManager.NextCall(UserID).First();
}

public IEnumerable<long> NextCall(long UserID)
{
    int returnID;
    UserExtended ue = null;

    try
    {
        if (!CacheUsers.ContainsKey(UserID))
        {
            AddUser(UserID);
        }

        ue = CacheUsers.First(p => p.Key == UserID).Value;

        if (ue.NextCampaign != null)
        {
            QueueItemPersonal qp = ue.NextFromPersonalQueue();

            if (qp != null)
            {
                returnID =  qp.CampaignPersonID;
            }
            else 
            { 
                QueueItemScheduled qs = ue.NextCampaign.NextFromScheduleQueue();

                if (qs != null)
                {
                    returnID  = qs.CampaignPersonID;
                }
                else 
                { 
                    QueueItemGeneral qg = ue.NextCampaign.NextFromGeneralQueue();

                    if (qg != null)
                    {
                        returnID = qg.CampaignPersonID;
                    }                  
                    else
                    {
                         returnID = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            ue.NextCampaign.fillGeneralQueue();
            ue.setNextCampaign();
        }
        else
        {
            returnID = 0;
        }

        yield return returnID;
    }
    //catch
    //{
    //    yield return 0;
    //}
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Well since he calls First() after yield returns one item it's done.

Comment: With that code I will first execute ue.setNextCampaign(); then return the ID but I want opposite of that

Comment: @mcorluka, why is order of execution important?

Comment: This is the situation I have the person in call centar and I want when he click Next Call get ID of person he must Call. He must first get ID of a person from service then service refresh Queue of calls... I hope you understood what I want